# Filtering lists and nested lists using streams

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-lists, predicate

I have to filter a list, based on the value of an attribute. I also have to filter a nested list, based on one of its attributes, and likewise for another nested list. I wondered how this might be possible in a stream.

Example:

- I want to filter a List of Foo's, retaining only those where Foo.type = "fooType".

  - Within these retained Foo's, I wish to filter a list of Bar's on Bar.type = "barType", retaining only those which satisfy the given condition.

    - I then want to filter the list of NestedAttribute's on NestedAttribute.id = "attributeID", only retaining those which match this condition.

I want to return the list of foo's, from this.

```
void test() {
        List<Foo> listOfFoos;
        
        for(Foo foo : listOfFoos) {

            if(foo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("fooType")) {
                // If foo matches condition, retain it
                for(Bar bar : foo.getBars()) {
                    if(bar.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("barType")) {
                        // If Bar matches condition, retain this Bar 
                        for(NestedAttribute attribute : bar.getNestedAttributes()) {

                            if(attribute.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("attributeID")) {
                                // retain this attribute and return it. 
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // remove bar from the list
                        foo.getBars().remove(bar);
                    }
                }
            }else {
                // remove Foo from list
                listOfFoos.remove(foo);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Foo {
        String type;
        List<Bar> bars;
    }
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Bar {
        String type;
        List<NestedAttribute> nestedAttributes;
    }
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class NestedAttribute {
        String id;
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
    listOfFoos = listOfFoos.stream()
        .filter(foo -> foo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("fooType"))
        .flatMap(foo -> foo.getBars().stream()
                .filter(bar -> bar.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("barType"))
                .flatMap(bar -> bar.getNestedAttributes().stream()
                        .filter(nested -> nested.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("attributeID"))
                        )
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Have you tried this using streams? You need `listOfFoos.stream.filter(...)`. What's the output? The listOfFoos?

Comment: I've tried streams, and yes returning a listOfFoos, but im getting those foo's which match a given scenario, but not removing the nested values which dont match it

Comment: Then just invert the expression of `filter`.

Comment: Why would  a Foo instance be anything but a fooType?  Same for Bar.  It doesn't make sense to me that you need to check Foo's to make certain they're a fooType.  It would make more sense (at least to me) that a Foo instance can hold many type and you want to ensure it is a bar type.

Comment: it's an arbitrary example, im hoping to filter on a given parameter for a given value.. I could swap 'type' for 'id' for example

Comment: But I am still unsure what you want to return.  Would it be `Foos` that only contains `Bars` that only contain `NestedAttributes` that only contain `attributeID`?  Or do you just want to resturn the `List<NestedAttribute>`?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the **stream filter** lambda expression, but the resultant cohesion will unfortunately not be great:

```
listOfFoos.stream()
  .filter(foo ->
     (foo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("fooType") && (foo.getBars().stream()
        .filter((bar -> (bar.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("barType") && (bar.getNestedAttributes().stream()
           .filter(nestedAttribute -> nestedAttribute.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("attributeID"))
            ).count() > 0)))
         ).count() > 0))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you wanted all the "fooType" foos, with only the "barType" bars and "attributeID" nestedAttibutes within.

Then something like:

```
List<Foo> selected = listOfFoos.stream()

    // keep the "footType" foos
    .filter(foo -> foo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("fooType"))

    // map each foo to itself
    .map(foo -> {
        // ... but sneakily remove the non-"barType" bars
        foo.getBars().removeIf(bar -> !bar.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("barType"))
        return foo;
    }

    // map each foo to itself again
    .map(foo -> {
        // iterate over the bars
        foo.getBars().forEach(bar -> 

            // remove the non-"attributeID" nested attributes
            bar.getNestedAttributes().removeIf(nested -> !nested.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("attributeID"))

        );            
        return foo;            
    }
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this is actually modifying the nested collections, instead of just creating a stream. To obtain filtered nested collections would require either doing it like this, or creating new nested collections.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for

```
public static List<Foo> filterList(List<Foo> list, String fooType, String barType, String attrID) {
     return list.stream()
             .filter(foo -> foo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(fooType))
             .peek(foo -> foo.getBars().removeIf(bar -> !bar.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(barType)))
             .peek(foo -> foo.getBars().forEach(bar -> bar.getNestedAttributes().removeIf(attr -> !attr.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(attrID))))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

EDIT: Added classes implementation with toString for test print

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList barListAttrs = new ArrayList();
        barListAttrs.add(new NestedAttribute("testAttr1"));
        barListAttrs.add(new NestedAttribute("id"));
        barListAttrs.add(new NestedAttribute("testAttr2"));

        ArrayList fooListBars = new ArrayList();
        fooListBars.add(new Bar("bar", barListAttrs));
        fooListBars.add(new Bar("testBar1", new ArrayList<>()));

        List<Foo> listFoo = new ArrayList<>();
        listFoo.add(new Foo("testFoo1", new ArrayList<>()));
        listFoo.add(new Foo("foo", fooListBars));

        for (Foo f : listFoo) {
            System.out.println(f);
        }

        List<Foo> list2 = filterList(listFoo, "foo", "bar", "id");
        System.out.println("\n\n---------------- RESULT ----------------\n");

        for (Foo f : list2) {
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
}

class Foo {
    String type;
    List<Bar> bars;

    public Foo(String type, List<Bar> bars) {
        this.type = type;
        this.bars = bars;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(type);
        str.append(" [");
        for (Bar b : bars) {
            str.append(b.toString());
            str.append(" ");
        }
        str.append("]");
        return str.toString();
    }
}

class Bar {
    String type;
    List<NestedAttribute> nestedAttributes;

    public Bar(String type, List<NestedAttribute> nestedAttributes) {
        this.type = type;
        this.nestedAttributes = nestedAttributes;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<NestedAttribute> getNestedAttributes() {
        return nestedAttributes;
    }

    public void setNestedAttributes(List<NestedAttribute> nestedAttributes) {
        this.nestedAttributes = nestedAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(type);
        str.append(" [");
        for (NestedAttribute na : nestedAttributes) {
            str.append(na.toString());
            str.append(" ");
        }
        str.append("]");
        return str.toString();
    }
}

class NestedAttribute {
    String id;

    public NestedAttribute(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am certain you can accomplish this with streams but I don't believe that it lends itself to that very well.  The problem is that streams along with map replaces the existing element with a new one, perhaps of different type.
But it is necessary to maintain access to previously constructed types to build the hierarchy. `mapMulti` would be a possibility but it could get cluttered (More so than below).

The following creates a new hierarchy without any deletions **(removal in a random access list can be expensive since either a linear search is required or a repeated copying of values)** and adds those instances which contain the type you want. At each conditional, a new instance is created.  At those times, the previous list is updated to reflect the just created instance.

After generating some variable data, this seems to work as I understand the goal.

```
static List<Foo> test(List<Foo> listOfFoos) {
    List<Foo> newFooList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Foo foo : listOfFoos) {
        if (foo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("fooType")) {
            Foo newFoo = new Foo(foo.getType(), new ArrayList<>());
            newFooList.add(newFoo);

            for (Bar bar : foo.getBars()) {
                if (bar.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("barType")) {
                    Bar newBar = new Bar(bar.getType(), new ArrayList<>());
                    newFoo.getBars.add(newBar);

                    for (NestedAttribute attribute : bar
                            .getNestedAttributes()) {
                        if (attribute.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "attributeID")) {
                            newBar.getNestedAttributes().add(attribute);
                                    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newFooList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option. It's not fluent statement but three fluent one.

```
        Function<Bar, List<NestedAttribute>> filterAttributes
                = bar -> bar.getNestedAttributes()
                .stream()
                .filter(a -> "attributeId".equals(a.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Function<Foo, List<Bar>> filterBarsAndAttributes
                = foo -> foo.getBars()
                .stream()
                .filter(b -> "barType".equals(b.getType()))
                .peek(b -> b.setNestedAttributes(filterAttributes.apply(b)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        listOfFoos.stream()
                .forEach(f -> f.setBars(filterBarsAndAttributes.apply(f)));
```